# Use git stash apply to reach recent head commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-stash

I worked in the branch master and `HEAD` points to commit `1`.

During my work time, my colleague has pushed his commit with number `2` into the master branch. And now the `HEAD` points to commit `2`.

After commit of my colleague, I want to update the pushes of my colleague into my current working directory. But I have still my own local changes in my working directory.

In this case I put firstly my local change into local stash. And then I pull my local working directory in recent head commit `2`.

So my question now, how can I apply the changes in stash to current `HEAD` commit `2`?

If I use `git stash apply` or `git stash add`, I will go to the old state based with 0001. I don't want this. I want to push my local changes into the recent commit `2`.

My thought here is, maybe I can use somehow cherry pick?

Comment: `git stash apply` should work if there's no conflict.

Comment: To continue on the above comment, `git stash` is just a commit (actually, 2 commits, or sometimes even 3), and when you apply a stash, you're just applying a diff on top of wherever you are.

Comment: So that means, after stashing and update in recent head commit 0002 using pull, if i use git stash apply, git will put my local changes saved in stash into recent commit 0002? Not the past state local changes with base version 0001?

Comment: Stash apply would only apply the patch. Just do `git stash apply` and resolve the conflicts. You won't lose any of your colleague's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stash changes you can apply them later at any point. It work analogical to a merge, wich applies changes to your working directory. If you have conflicting changes you can resolve them in the same way as merge conflicts.